# Replacing characters with numbers in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I have started to do the questions on Project Euler regarding lists of names which need to be replaced with their corresponding position in the alphabet. In [Problem 22](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=22) I need to replace, the letters with numbers:

```
names = ["MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA"....
replace = ??????
char2num a = map replace a
score (a,b) = a * (sum $ map char2num b)
answer = sum $ map score (zip [1..] (sort names))
```

What I cannot find is how to replace the characters with their place in the alphabet. How would I go about making something to do the replace function (preferably not regex)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ord` function in the `Data.Char` module gives an integer code for each character. Given that, this would be the function you're looking for:

```
import Data.Char

replace :: Char -> Int
replace c = ord c - ord 'A' + 1
```

I'm not sure if `ord c` will return the ASCII code for a character, or the unicode codepoint, or if the result is machine dependent. To abstract from that, we simply subtract the code for `'A'` from the result, and add `1` because we want the alphabet to start at `1` instead of `0`.

An easy way to find to find such a function is [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/).
There you can search for functions in the standard Haskell packages by entering its type. In this case `ord` is the second result when searching for [`Char -> Int`](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?q=Char%20-%3E%20Int).